# How do I determine if a shell script is running with root permissions?

Tags: shell, permissions, sudo

I've got a script I want to require be run with su privileges, but the interesting scripted command that will fail comes very late in the script, so I'd like a clean test up front to determine if the scrip will fail without SU capabilities.

What is a good way to do this for bash, sh, and/or csh?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-root-user-check-script.html?

Comment: That looks pretty good. Why didn't you give this as an answer? :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if running as root in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215973/how-to-check-if-running-as-root-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

bash/sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# (Use #!/bin/sh for sh)
if [ `id -u` = 0 ] ; then
        echo "I AM ROOT, HEAR ME ROAR"
fi
```

csh:

```
#!/bin/csh
if ( `id -u` == "0" ) then
        echo "I AM ROOT, HEAR ME ROAR"
endif
```

Comment: This code will not work in a POSIX shell (`/bin/sh`).  The `[[` command and `EUID` variable are specific to bash -- they're not defined in the POSIX specification.

Comment: Also #!/bin/bash is almost always wrong.  If you must use bash (which is really not preferred) use /usr/bin/env bash

Comment: It seems like bash **is** preferred by people who specifically mention bash in their questions.

Answer (score 13):

You might add something like that at the beginning of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ROOTUID="0"

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne "$ROOTUID" ] ; then
    echo "This script must be executed with root privileges."
    exit 1
fi
```