# How to check if running as root in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, root

I'm writing a script that requires root level permissions, and I want to make it so that if the script is not run as root, it simply echoes "Please run as root." and exits.

Here's some pseudocode for what I'm looking for:

```
if (whoami != root)
  then echo "Please run as root"

  else (do stuff)
fi

exit
```

How could I best (cleanly and securely) accomplish this? Thanks!

Ah, just to clarify: the (do stuff) part would involve running commands that in-and-of themselves require root. So running it as a normal user would just come up with an error. This is just meant to cleanly run a script that requires root commands, without using sudo inside the script, I'm just looking for some syntactic sugar.

Comment: (1) make it not executable by anything else then root (2) arrange further permissions as well.. (3) `id -u` returns `0` for root.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

A few answers have been given, but it appears that the best method is to use is:

- `id -u`
- If run as root, will return an id of 0.

This appears to be more reliable than the other methods, and it seems that it return an id of 0 even if the script is run through `sudo`.

Here is an example of checking if running as root in a bash script (using `id -u` inline to do so):

```
#/bin/bash
if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]
  then echo Please run this script as root or using sudo!
  exit
fi
# Remainder of script goes below this line
```

Comment: Except if there's no "root" but you still have necessary privileges. Short correct answer is - use it for cosmetic purposes only.

Comment: This solution also works in sh and dash, but `id` is not a shell built-in the way that `$EUID` is in bash and zsh: it requires having coreutils installed (which is a common enough assumption, so that seems okay to me). This command and flag also work on FreeBSD but I'm not sure how to check if this was part of a package installation.

Answer (score 645):

The $EUID environment variable holds the current user's UID. Root's UID is 0. Use something like this in your script:

```
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi
```

**Note:** If you get `2: [: Illegal number:` check if you have `#!/bin/sh` at the top and change it to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: It seems that good permissions and having this is a double layer of security

Comment: I think is better to compare string with string, number with number. using double brackets, you could use > directly with no quotation [[ $EUID > 0 ]]

Comment: I got `2: [: Illegal number:` warning until changed it to Sergio's version.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you use `sudo`, `$EUID` does not change. So if a script is run with `sudo`, this check would incorrectly complain that it doesn't have root privileges (which is what you actually want - you don't have to _be_ root).

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the closing bracket!

Comment: @thekiwi5000 The semicolon is only required if the `then` is on the same line as the condition...

Comment: @StephenAngelico Sudo should work.  If you're testing it by doing $ sudo echo $EUID ; that's a bad test and will fail because $EUID is expanded before the command is passed to sudo.  Try putting echo $EUID in a test script and running that with sudo.

Comment: `$EUID` doesn't work in `dash` (a common `/bin/sh` implementation).

Comment: Alternatively : `if (($EUID))`. Props to `ormaaj` and `gnoo` from `#bash` on `irc.libera.chat`

Comment: Is it `bash` of vanilla `shell`?

Comment: @StephenAngelico `sudo bash -c 'echo "$EUID"'` shows 0 on bash version 5.1.4(1) and sudo version 1.9.5p2. Please add a reproducer that shows a scenario where `sudo` does not change the euid!

Comment: @Luc Same bash and sudo versions: `echo $EUID -> 1000`, `sudo echo $EUID -> 1000`

Comment: @Luc I concede your point though, your command is more equivalent to running a script. In a terminal, $EUID is unchanged when running a process with sudo, whereas in a script, the environment in created from root ownership.

Comment: It's probably best to exit with a non-zero exit code to indicate an error. Replace `exit` with `exit 1`

Answer (score 105):

In a bash script, you have several ways to check if the running user is root.

As a **warning**, do not check if a user is root by using the `root` username. Nothing guarantees that the user with ID 0 is called `root`. It's a very strong convention that is broadly followed but anybody could rename the superuser another name.

I think the best way when using **bash** is to use `$EUID`, from the man page:

```
EUID   Expands to the effective user ID of the current  user,  initialized
       at shell startup.  This variable is readonly.
```

This is a better way than `$UID` which could be changed and not reflect the real user running the script.

```
if (( $EUID != 0 )); then
    echo "Please run as root"
    exit
fi
```

A way I approach that kind of problem is by injecting `sudo` in my commands when not run as root. Here is an example:

```
SUDO=''
if (( $EUID != 0 )); then
    SUDO='sudo'
fi
$SUDO a_command
```

This ways my command is run by root when using the superuser or by `sudo` when run by a regular user.

If your script is always to be run by root, simply set the rights accordingly (`0500`).

Comment: If the person who is trying to run the script does not have sudo privileges, this will cause the error to be thrown and the command will not run? Just want to make sure, I understand correctly.

Comment: I am not sure this answer is 100% completely correct. On RHEL7.2 using Bash 4.2.46... if I `printf $EUID` with or without sudo, I get my own UID back. If I use `id -u` I get my UID and when I invoke it with sudo I get 0 back. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @0xSheepdog, it's possible that on the bash cli, the $EUID variable expansion gets resolved first, then sudo changes user. Therefore you would get that behavior, but in scripts, everything would still work fine.

Comment: @AlexanderBird Good point, thank you! I did not do any real testing, just reported my experience.

Comment: Use a "herestring" for your test to prevent local shell expansion of the variable. Compare `sudo bash <<<'echo $EUID'` to `bash <<<'echo $EUID'`. More about the heredoc-like herestring at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html

Answer (score 103):

My one-liner:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Please run as root." >&2; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: You could consider integrating [Jeremy J Starcher's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18216143/1504300)  with this part, in the end it's always the same stuff...

Comment: I know that from the terminal, when I forget to prefix something with `sudo` I can simply type `sudo !!` and it does the work for me, rather than pressing the UP arrow, going to the beginning of the line, and adding `sudo ` by hand. Not sure if that is a BASH thing or a SUDO thing or other, but it works most all of the time.

Comment: @0xSheepdog: It's a Bash thing (and a feature of some other shells such as csh, where IIRC it originated).

Answer (score 48):

In this answer, let it be clear, I presume the reader is able to understand the difference betweeen *modern* shells like [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) and others vs portable [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shells like [`dash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash).

I believe there is not much to explain here since the highly voted answers do a good job of explaining much of it.

Yet, if there is anything to explain further, don't hesitate to comment, I will do my best by filling the gaps.

---

### Optimized all-round solution for performance and reliability; all shells compatible

**New solution:**

```sh
# bool function to test if the user is root or not
is_user_root () { [ "${EUID:-$(id -u)}" -eq 0 ]; }
```

---

#### Benchmark (save to file `is_user_root__benchmark`)

```sh
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|                           is_user_root() benchmark                           |
#|                  "Bash is fast while Dash is slow in this"                   |
#|                          Language: POSIX shell script                        |
#|                     Copyright: 2020-2021 Vlastimil Burian                    |
#|                      M@il: info[..]vlastimilburian[..]cz                     |
#|                               License: GPL 3.0                               |
#|                                 Version: 1.2                                 |
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

readonly iterations=10000

# intentionally, the file does not have an executable bit, nor it has a shebang
# to use it, just call the file directly with your shell interpreter like:

# bash is_user_root__benchmark    ## should take a fraction of one second
# dash is_user_root__benchmark    ## could take around 10 seconds

is_user_root () { [ "${EUID:-$(id -u)}" -eq 0 ]; }

print_time   () { date +"%T.%2N"; }
print_start  () { printf '%s' 'Start  : '; print_time; }
print_finish () { printf '%s' 'Finish : '; print_time; }

printf '%s\n' '___is_user_root()___'; print_start
                   
i=1; while [ "$i" -lt "$iterations" ]; do
    is_user_root
    i=$((i+1))
done; print_finish
```

Examples of use and duration:

```sh
$ dash is_user_root__benchmark 
___is_user_root()___
Start  : 03:14:04.81
Finish : 03:14:13.29

$ bash is_user_root__benchmark 
___is_user_root()___
Start  : 03:16:22.90
Finish : 03:16:23.08
```

---

### Explanation

Since it is multitude times faster to read the `$EUID` standard [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) variable, the effective user ID number, than executing `id -u` command to [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-ly find the user ID, this solution combines both into a nicely packed function. If, and only if, the `$EUID` is for any reason not available, the `id -u` command will get executed, ensuring we get the proper return value *no matter the circumstances*.

---

### Why I post this solution after so many years the OP has asked

Well, if I see correctly, there does seem to be a missing piece of code above.

You see, there are many *variables* which have to be taken into account, and one of them is **combining performance and reliability**.

---

### Portable *pure* [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) solution + Example of usage of the above function

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# bool function to test if the user is root or not (POSIX only)
is_user_root ()
{
    [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
}

if is_user_root; then
    echo 'You are the almighty root!'
    # You can do whatever you need...
else
    echo 'You are just an ordinary user.' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

---

### Conclusion

As much as you possibly don't like it, the Unix / Linux environment has diversified a lot. Meaning there are people who like [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), and other modern shells so much, they don't even think of portability ([POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)). It is nowadays a matter of personal choice and needs.

Comment: You could use POSIX substitution `${EUID:=$(id -u)}` to achieve near-perfect performance match in case of repetitive execution of the same test.

Comment: @AnrDaemon Hello, I've just tried it, and it's working as expected. Did you down-vote because of it? I saw 1 down just after you commented, just did not have time to respond until now. Sorry about that. Anyway, thanks for teaching me just another expansion. :) I will think about it, and maybe change the whole thing... Cheers

Comment: No, I downvoted because it is principally impossible to test for permissions based on user's name/id alone. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215973/how-to-check-if-running-as-root-in-a-bash-script/52586842?noredirect=1#comment125415762_28776100) below.

Comment: @AnrDaemon Do you have any proof on EUID or id -u being whatever you want to call it .. e.g imperfect?

Comment: It is not imperfect, it merely does what it is designed for. But does not make any claims other than what it says. $EUID MAY BE 0, but that doesn't mean you have rights to do anything you pleased (fakeroot f.e.), the reverse is also true - you may not be EUID=0 but have the necessary permissions (Cygwin, there's no UID=0 by design).

Answer (score 39):

There is a simple check for the user being `root`.

```
# Fancy red-colored `error` function with `stderr` redirection with `exit`.
error ()
{
    { printf '\E[31m'; echo "$@"; printf '\E[0m'; } >&2
    exit 1
}

# Test for root user.
if [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]; then
    error "Do not run this as the root user"
fi
```

This also assumes that you want to exit with a 1 if you fail. The `error` function is some flair that sets output text to red (not needed, but pretty classy if you ask me).

Comment: Oh, that's just a small flair thing. Doesn't matter all that much, but I'll attach it.

Comment: That's pretty cool! If I may suggest a few improvements: (1) move the newline to the end; (2) write to standard error rather than standard output; (3) only set the color if standard error is a terminal (rather than risk writing escape characters into log-files or `less` or whatnot); and (4) set a background-color, so the text will be readable regardless of the background-color of the user's terminal. So, something like `function error () { if [[ -t 2 ]] ; then echo $'\033[31;2;47m'"$@"$'\033[0m' ; else echo "$@" ; fi >&2 ; }`. (Tweak as desired.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be "-ne" instead of "-eq"?

Comment: @CarlosRendon Slater's code is to *prevent* something from being run as root.  (This is opposite what the OP was asking for, but the method of checking would be the same.)

Answer (score 30):

As @wrikken mentioned in his comments, `id -u` is a much better check for root.

In addition, with proper use of `sudo`, you could have the script check and see if it is running as root.  If not, have it recall itself via `sudo` and then run with root permissions.

Depending on what the script does, another option may be to set up a `sudo` entry for whatever specialized commands the script may need.

Answer (score 15):

1- Read official GNU Linux documentation, there are many ways to do it correctly.

2- make sure you put the shell signature to avoid errors in interpretation:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

3- this is my script

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [[ $EUID > 0 ]]; then  
  echo "Please run as root/sudo"
  exit 1
else
  #do your stuff
fi
```

Comment: For bash, I like this condition: ((EUID)) (equivalent to [[ $EUID > 0 ]]) which I think is cleaner.

Comment: I respect your taste, but if it works, it is a matter of preference and style. For me it is cleaner to show that 0 is the condition to be root numerically

Answer (score 11):

Very simple way just put:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" = "root" ]; then
    # you are root
else
    # you are not root
fi
```

The benefit of using this instead of `id` is that you can check whether a certain non-root user is running the command, too; eg.

```
if [ "$(whoami)" = "john" ]; then
    # you are john
else
    # you are not john
fi
```

Editor's Note: Either prefer using POSIX-compatible test command and comparison `[... = ...]` or you can use Bash/+other shells specific `[[... == ...]]`.

Comment: if you test the user with a string "root", aren't you allowing to run anyone that is named "root"?

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question about `whoami` rather than using `id`; the `whoami` command can also be used to check for *other* users than root, by name.

Answer (score 9):

One simple way to make the script only runnable by root is to start the script with [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/bin/su root
```

Comment: I'm curious why this answer isn't voted higher? It seems like the simplest and cleanest. Are there disadvantages here?

Comment: @Bassinator I believe some people say it won't run on certain nix's but it has work flawlessly on my Linux so far. Try it! Maybe this answer has come late to the race but I'm trying to add knowleadge that is simple to the community (instead of giving similiar answers, like most on this thread :/ ) Vote this up if you are lucky to read this and it works on your machine

Comment: @TamusJRoyce If the goal is checking if you are running as a root and not forcing the script to run only as root, why is then in every answer , after the check if is running as root, they make the script `exit`? And still those answers are being upvoted? I guess people implicitly do not want the script to be run as root. So I'm following that way of thinking, with a simpler answer. But yeah, you can also learn from the more verbose answers above

Comment: @alexandre1985 Exactly. Scenario:  If running as root, maybe you want a script to default to installing the program globally when it asks how you want it installed. Otherwise, the default is set to install it locally. Instead of hitting enter, the user could choose to install it global or local. But if they like the default, they can hit enter. And they will not be prompted with a password. Your shebang will never "check" if you are root (per title). But I still think this answer is useful.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce totally makes sense your comment. Indeed is a concern and this solution is not for that use case. You opened my perspectives. You are right. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work in my `bash` (`GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
`).

Comment: @KarlMorrison Just tested and still works in mine `GNU bash, versão 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Doesn't work because I disabled root login and some Linux distros disable root login.

Comment: A couple of disadvantages I can see, main issue is you need to know root's password, presumably this relies on the shell specified in /etc/passwd, it may behave strangely if the shell and script are not both bash.  su and  su - are not the same thing trick hardcodes not using a login shell. It will cd if you do use a login shell and fail.

Comment: Which password is needed is not indicated to the user, Unlike sudo password is not remembered. There is an extra fork compared to checking $EUID. forks even if you are already root. Unlike use of sudo the script executed is not logged. Its a cool trick but not necessarily obvious when reading the script, and  like other shebang tricks it does not work if run bash -x ./script and will only fail when root is needed compared to other answers here that have an else clause to the check and fail fast.

Comment: also if you run this script from another program and and want to send signals, (e.g. kill -9 if it takes too long) it wont work as expected.

Comment: this doesn't work for some reason always says auth failure with the same password I use to run sudo su.

Comment: @Brad Your problem may be with the su command. Try checking your PAM configuration

Answer (score 5):

If the script really requires root access then its file permissions should reflect that. Having a root script executable by non-root users would be a red flag. I encourage you not to control access with an `if` check.

```
chown root:root script.sh
chmod u=rwx,go=r script.sh
```

Comment: If someone has their permissions in order this works great, but I feel like overuse of the `777` bomb makes this check a little faulty for the kind of users that would make the mistake in the first place.

Comment: This is assuming the user is running an executable script. If the user just calls `bash /path/to/script` it can still be ran even though `o=r`

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Sorry, you are not root." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

<sub>Note on edit: Backticks are considered deprecated by now ([many further notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/126755)).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It is important to notice that whenever you run a script using `sudo` the 'user context' or environment will switch to `root`.

#### But Teo what that means?

Well, my young padawan, this means that if a `padawan` user runs a script that contains a tilde (`~`)  using `sudo`, whenever the bash will expand `~` the result will be `/root` and not `/home/<user>` (i.e., in this case `/home/padawan`), or if you create either a directory or a file the owner and group will be `root` and not the  that executed the script in this case `padawan`, because the user environment was switched.

For instance, lets check this script `install-app.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_UID=0   # Only users with $UID 0 have root privileges.
E_NOTROOT=87 # Non-root exit error.

## Prevent the execution of the script if the user has no root privileges
if [ "${UID:-$(id -u)}" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ]; then
    echo 'Error: root privileges are needed to run this script'
    exit $E_NOTROOT
fi
...
mkdir -vp ~/app/init
touch config
...
touch /home/<user>/app/init/profile
service mysql start
...
```

If we run using `sudo`:

```bash
sudo install-app.sh
```

This will create directories and a `config` file will look like this:

```bash
##
## ~ (/root)
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root    4096 Nov 23 20:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096 Nov 15 19:04 ../
...
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Nov 25 14:30 app/
...
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Nov 16 19:08 tmp/

## ~/app (/root/app)
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:33 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:33 init/

## ~/app/init (/root/app/init)
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:30 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 25 14:33 config

## /home/<user>/app/conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 <user> <user> 4096 Nov 25 14:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 <user> <user> 4096 Nov 25 14:30 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Nov 25 14:43 profile
```

As you can see the script is a total mess. Now the `<user>` cannot get access to the `profile` file, nor can they modify the `config` without using `sudo`. At the beginning, this may seem not important, but I assure you that if your project gets bigger, someone will run the script and mess with your system.

#### Recommendation:

Prompt the user to verify if they are a sudoer. Then, add `sudo` to the commands that require it.

The following code shows how to apply these changes to the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
E_NOTROOT=87 # Non-root exit error.

## Prevent the execution of the script if the user has no root privileges
## Check if is sudoer
if ! $(sudo -l &>/dev/null); then
    echo 'Error: root privileges are needed to run this script'
    exit $E_NOTROOT
fi
...
mkdir -vp ~/app/init
touch config
...
touch /home/<user>/app/init/profile
sudo service mysql start
...
```

This modification allows the user to run the script like this:

```bash
install-app.sh
```

The user will be requested to insert his password to verify if is sudoer. After,`mkdir -vp ~/app/init` will create the file in the user's home:

```bash
/home/<user>/app/init
/home/<user>/app/init/config
/home/<user>/app/init/profile
```

Also, I recommend to get the users homer directory and use it as a constant.

```
## Defines user home directory
USER_HOME_DIR=$(getent passwd ${SUDO_USER:-$USER} | cut -d: -f6)
...
mkdir -vp "$USER_HOME_DIR/app/init"
...
```

Answer (score 3):

**`id -u`** is much better than `whoami`, since some systems like **Android** may not provide the word root.

---

Example command:

```
# whoami
```

Example output:

```sh
whoami: unknown uid 0
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the correct way to check it, is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You are root."
else
    echo "You are NOT root." >&2
fi
```

OP's Note: you may see ["Testing For Root" section on linuxcommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0080.php).

Editor's Note: I have slightly adjusted this shell snippet to be POSIX-compatible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem using: `id -u`, `$EUID` and `whoami`, is all of them give false positive when I fake the root, like this:

```
$ fakeroot
```

`id`:

```
$ id -u
0
```

`$EUID`:

```
$ echo $EUID
0
```

`whoami`:

```
$ whoami
root
```

---

Then a reliable (and hacking) way is verify if the user has access to the `/root` directory:

```
$ ls /root >/dev/null 2>&1 && is_root=true || is_root=false; echo "$is_root"
```

Comment: Checking for `/root/` folder access may also give false positive when access rights to the folder are altered.

Comment: I understand that /root DIR is only accessible by root, of course if root user change permission you can access but this is not a common case.

Comment: What is the advantage in thwarting fakeroot usage? The user is clearly annoyed by the check and tries to circumvent it. A system call down the line will error out if they don't have sufficient privileges, or maybe they set capabilities or run in a different environment, so you might as well let them try it.

Comment: @Luc this is an uncommon scenario but suppose you have script wrapper to compile something from source code and you want to avoid download, configure and make commands for this specific task for standard user.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
[ "`id -u`" -ne 0 ] && echo "Please run me as root!"
```

Unlike all other answers, this script:

1. Does not depend on anything being *named* "root", such as the user name or a `/root` directory.
2. Is compatible with and tested on:

   - sh (`$EUID` is specific to bash and zsh)
   - bash
   - zsh
   - dash
   - csh and tsch (due to [backticks instead of `$()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752030/1201863))

   Only "fish" is a shell that is not compatible (there seems to be no way to have compatibility between the more commons shells above and fish).
3. Works on:

   - Linux with coreutils installed (even a minimal Debian, Ubuntu, etc. will have this)
   - FreeBSD
   - Android (based on [Smeterlink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366935/1201863))

   I'd be interested if anyone has a macOS or Windows Linux Subsystem machine to test this on as well! Please comment or edit this answer.
4. Detects:

   - `sudo` (tested version: 1.9.5p2)
   - `doas` (tested version: 6.8.1-2)
   - real root (switched user using `su` + password)

   Fakeroot is not detected, but if the user wants to pretend they're root, I see no reason to not let them.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are root and quit if you are not:

```
if ((EUID != 0)); then
    echo "Root or Sudo  Required for script ( $(basename $0) )"
    exit
fi
```

Or in this example, try to create a directory in root location then try after rights were elevated.

Check if you are root and if not elevate if possible :

```
# Fails to create these dirs (needs sudo)
mkdir /test-dir-$(basename $0)
rmdir /test-dir-$(basename $0)

if ((EUID != 0)); then
    echo "Granting root privileges for script ( $(basename $0) )"
    if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
        sudo "$0" "$@"
    else
        exec 1> output_file
        gksu "$0" "$@"
    fi
    exit
fi
echo "Root privileges granted..."
# Creates Dirs as it now has rights
mkdir /test-dir-$(basename $0)
rmdir /test-dir-$(basename $0)
```

Answer (score 0):

My one-liner:

```
[ "$(whoami)" != root ] && echo "Please, run as root." >&2 && exit 1
```

Tested under Debian, Ubuntu and Docker.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy Thanks for upvoting it to neutral. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same issue. The line `#!/bin/su root` would be an elegant method, but does not work on certain (higher) versions of bash, as mentioned by @basickarl. Further - this method will probably fail when you start the script with `/bin/bash ./some_script.(b)sh`.

I found [an other page on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272784) where the use of the environment variables `SUDO_UID` and `SUDO_USER` were used. When a normal user invokes a script with `sudo` these are available in the script. Otherwise they are empty. Also: when you are actually logged on as root these values are empty (or unset - not entirely sure) as well.

So this is the solution I'm currently using:

```bash
isSudo()
{
  local _fn="${FUNCNAME[0]}"
  if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -eq 0 ]] ; then
    if [[ ! -z "$SUDO_UID" && ! -z "$SUDO_USER" ]] ; then
      >2 echo -e "$_fn: invoked as sudo-user ($SUDO_USER)."
    else
      >2 echo -e "$_fn: invoked as root ($SUDO_USER)."
    fi
    return 0
  fi
  >2 echo "$_fn: not as root or as sudoer."
  return 1
}
```

Then use it like this eg.:

```bash
if $(isSudo) ; then
  echo -e "Script started as root or as sudoer."
else
  echo -e "Script not started as root or with sudo"
fi
```

The `>2` in front of the echo is to redirect the echo to stderr otherwise the `if` statement goes haywire and it's just for a little debugging. In stead of using an echo, you could save "root", "sudoer" or "user" in a local variable and let the function echo that back and then perform a `case` on that like this:

```bash
how_invoked()
{
  local _invoked_as="USER"
  if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -eq 0 ]] ; then
    if [[ ! -z "$SUDO_UID" && ! -z "$SUDO_USER" ]] ; then
      _invoked_as="SUDOER"
    else
      _invoked_as="ROOT"
    fi
  fi
  echo -n "$_invoked_as" # -n prevents newline
}
```

And then use it like this:

```bash
INVOKED_AS=$(how_invoked)
case $INVOKED_AS in
  USER)
    echo -e "Invoked as user." ;;
  SUDOER)
    echo -e "Invoked as sudoer." ;;
  ROOT)
    echo -e "Invoked as root." ;;
  *)
    echo -e "I'm confused" ;;
esac
```

Or if you just want to test for one of those:

```bash
if [ "$(how_invoked)" == "SUDOER" ] ; then
  echo -e "You are a sudoer."
else
  echo -e "You are NOT a sudoer."
fi
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think UID-based answers are any good here.

There can be privileged users, that where `UID != 0`, there can also be systems where `uid` or other commands are not available.

Most of the time the best solution seems to me to just try the command without root, and then do it again with root privileges or run a command that 100% requires root and to something if it fails with a permissions error.

Answer (score 0):

I just had that problem, but I solved it in a way that could also work for another user than root. The issue being that you know that root has an ID of 0, but you won't want to use another ID, as it is arbitrary and not guaranteed to be the same if you change your server or stuff.

```
if [ "$(whoami)" == root] # you could put another user name here instead of root
then
  # Do stuff
else
  # Do another kind of stuff
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

My two cents, running in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Display the UID variable
echo "Your UID is $UID"

# Check for root user via UID
if [ "$UID" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You are root"
else
    echo "You are not root user" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

My check for the `root` user, running in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$UID" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You are root."
else
    echo "You are just an ordinary user." >&2
fi
```