# Set sticky bit permission using bash script

Tags: bash

Can anyone guide, how to implement this linux command into a bash script

```
df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type d -perm -0002 2>/dev/null | xargs chmod a+t
```

Comment: Just put it in a file with `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning and make it executable. What's the problem?

Comment: Its gives me this error "chmod: missing operand after ‘a+t’"

Comment: It gives you that result because your pipeline does not provide you any output.

Comment: Note: this is simple [tag:shell], not *specific* [tag:bash].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simply

Put this in a file, add a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) *shebang* on 1st line:

```
#!/bin/sh

df --local -P |
    awk '{if (NR!=1) print $6}' |
    xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type d -perm -0002 2>/dev/null |
    xargs --no-run-if-empty chmod a+t
```

### But as this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I would write this something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

{ read foo; mapfile -t mpoints;} < <(df --local -P)
TEXTDOMAIN=libc
exec 2> >(exec grep -v '^find: .*'$"Permission denied"\$ >&2)
find "${mpoints[@]#*% }" -xdev -type d -perm -0002 -exec chmod a+t {} +
```

Short, quick and efficient!

Explanation:

- `read foo` just whipe header line of `df` output
- `mapfile -t` take rest of `df` output into `$mpoint` array, (`-t` remove a trailing *newline*).
- `exec ... {} ... +` will do approx same job than using `xargs`.
- `exec 2>... >&2` will silently delete lines matching *regex* in *STDERR*.
- `TEXTDOMAIN=libc` and `$"Permission denied"` will localize message to make this script work in many languages.

Comment: Its gives me this error "chmod: missing operand after ‘a+t’".

Comment: You my have to add `--no-run-if-empty` to last `xargs` for case `find` output is empty.

Comment: ... An put curly brace **into** quotes: `awk '{if (NR!=1) print $6}'`.

Comment: kool ..2 things come to mind
1) How to ensure root permission to execute the file
2) How to capture error in case of any and exist 1

Comment: @catty 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215973/how-to-check-if-running-as-root-in-a-bash-script